# How to understand clearly the feature importance computing in random forest model

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, machine-learning-model

I want to know the details of feature importance computing of random forest with gini index. I refer to this Chinese blog:https://www.jianshu.com/p/7a876bb876b9. But I don't understand clearly these mathematical forms in blog.

for example

As the node m after twos branches(Il, Ir) splitting, the gini index is computing as following
 [image: VIM1]

And  feature Xj in the decision ith tree ,and be in nodel of M set, and the feature importance of Xj in the ith tree is computing as following:

[image: VIM2]

And I confusing about M set, what's the meaning of M set? I think that the  feature Xj in ith tree just one node not a M set? If you guys have detailed computing method, please tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this formula for the Variable Importance Measure (VIM) based in Gini Impurity (GI)*:

$$VIM_{jm}^{(Gini)} = GI_m - GI_l - GL_r$$

Here, $m$ is a given node in a single decision tree which performs a split on feature $j$. For this node you can compute the Gini Impurity $GI_m$ (see * note at the very bottom for the formula). Now this node has two childs: a left node $l$ and a right node $r$. For these the Gini Impurities are $GI_l$ and $GL_r$ respectively. If you substract the Gini impurities of the child nodes from the Gini Impurity of node $m$, then you know by how much the split performed by this node has decreased the overall Gini Impurity. Because before the split it was $GI_m$ and after the split the remaining impurity is the sum of $GL_l$ of $GL_R$. Therefore, the difference ($GI_m - (GI_l + GL_r) 
= GI_m - GI_l - GL_r$) is the corresponding impurity reduction.

*(as a side node: this is the unweighted gini importance calculation since $GI_l$ and $GI_r$ are considered with equal weights. There are also different weighted versions. For details and a comparison please refer to ["The effect of splitting on random forests"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10994-014-5451-2.pdf)*, Hemant Ishwaran, Mach Learn (2015) 99:75–118)

For feature importance however, you're interested in the overall importance of each feature and not a single node. And a given feature can be present in different branches of a tree.

Here is an example:

[image: Decission Tree example]

(Source: "Artificial intelligence - a modern approach"; Norvig, Russell; 2010; 3rd Ed)

As you can see "Alternate?" is being used at multiple nodes. That is why they use set $M$ in the blog you posted to derive the overall importance of a feature $j$ in a tree $i$:

$$VIM_{ij}^{(Gini)} = \sum_{m \in M}VIM_{jm}^{(Gini)}$$

As a side node: in some papers and books the authors do not calculate the impurity indexed by features $j$ but indexed by a split value of a given node, e.g. $s$, (which of course operates on features). Don't get confused by that.

---

*
The Gini Impurity of a given node $m$ with $k \in K$ being the classes is defined as follows:
$$GI_m = \sum_{k \in K} \hat{p}_k(m)(1- \hat{p}_k(m)).$$

Where $\hat{p}_k(m)$ is the class frequency of class $k$ in node $m$.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation. I think initially that one feature can be only used one time in a tree.  you are so good at the random forest. Do you have own site or blog link?

Comment: @tktktk0711 Happy to help! If you think this sufficiently answers your question please accept the answer so the system marks your question as done. I do not have a blog or website :)

Comment: I have accepted, do you have other contact way, I want to communicate with you about tree model research topic

Comment: Unfortunately there is no feature to send personal messages on this site. You could open a chat room to discuss. But everyone else will be able to see the content.

Comment: thanks. If possible,  you can sent me email to me: 285662034@qq.com